# Show decimal places if not a complete whole number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have numbers in cells in Excel. I want the numbers formatted so that if they have decimal places they show to a maximum of two, and if they have no decimal places it doesn't show any.

For example:

```
•   1 should be formatted as 1 NOT 1.00
•   0.75 should be formatted as .75
•   0.2 should be formatted as .2 
•   0 should be formatted as 0
```

The closest custom format code I've come up with is 0.##. Unfortunately this formats 1.00 as 1. (note the extra decimal point).

How can I create a custom format code to remove the decimal point on cell values the report a full whole number?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use another column and round:

```
=ROUND(A1, 2)
```

You can also use a custom conditional format.  First, set the format to 0.## like you have, then select all of the applicable cells or the entire column and set a custom conditional format by selecting Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules from the Home ribbon:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Then click the New Rule button, and select Use a formula to determine which cells to format, and set the formula to `=ROUND(A1, 0) = ROUND(A1, 2)` where A1 is the first cell in the selected cells.  It will look like so:

[image: Conditional Formatting Continued]

Now click the Format button and set the Number format to General or just `#`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on MrExcel.com:

> This is not beautiful but i think it works

Assuming formatting A1

1. First format A1 as Number with 1 decimal place
2. Go to Conditional Formatting 
   New Rule
   Use a formula to.. (the last option)

   and insert this formula
   =SEARCH(".0",TEXT(A1,"0.0"))

   Click the Format button
   and pick Number with 0 decimal places

   Ok, Ok

   done

   Now you can use the Format Painter to apply the format to other cells.

   HTH

   M. 
   Here's the link: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/510333-custom-format-if-number-integer-dont-show-decimals-but.html
   I tested this and it does work. Just change decimal places from one to two.